# How can I disable all warnings for a single file with Clang 3.8?

Tags: clang

I'm using Clang 3.8 to compile *one* file that comes from a different source in a project. This is a temporary crutch, as this file is an addition to a library that I also use, and the code it has will be part of that library's next release. However, these people develop with less stringent warning flags than I do.

I'm not interested in these warnings as they're benign, I don't maintain that file, and it'll go away within a few months. Of course, I can selectively remove a warning or two, but I think that it makes more sense in this case to disable all and every warnings that it generates because I could change the warning settings of my project later and more occurrences could come out of it.

I've tried `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"`, but Clang warns that `-Weverything` is an unknown warning group.

How can I ask Clang to not generate any warnings for that file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Indeed, the "-Weverything" is not a group of warnings, but just a special option passed to the compiler. Here is code that handles this case: [lib/Basic/Warnings.cpp:118](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Basic/Warnings.cpp#L118)

You still can compile your problematic source file using slightly different rules/flags as you use for others sources:

```
clang -Wno-everything foo.c
```

However, I'd recommend to disable each warning explicitly using `#pragma`.

In case you disable all warnings, and then upgrade your compiler, then you may miss some new warnings, which could be important (e.g. undefined behaviour checks, security checks, etc).

Also, imagine what happens if the file is not gone after three months, but stays in the project forever.

Comment: The file in question is LLVM's MemorySSA pass. If there's any issue with it, chances are that I won't feel qualified to fix it. I'm also not sure that I could maintain it out of tree myself if it was dropped.

Comment: In other words, if the file isn't gone in three months, I'll have much worse problems than a few warnings ;)

Comment: If you want to disable it for e.g. included headers use `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"`

Comment: @ErikAigner, is that something that started working recently? I called it out in my question as it didn't work in early 2016.

Comment: Using the "clang -Wno-everything foo.c" in Makefile gives you error "*** missing separator.  Stop."

Answer (score 9):

If you need your compiler flags to be consistent between GCC and Clang, they both have the `-w` flag:

```sh
$ clang --help | grep -i suppress
  -w                      Suppress all warnings
```